# Can I setup router using WiFi?

Tags: router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration, firmware, setup

Can I setup [Asuswrt-Merlin](https://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/) on my ASUS RT-N66U for the first time using WiFi (not Ethernet)? I need to do this because I don't have a laptop with an Ethernet port.

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Default the router, it will allow you to connect with no encryption or security, then web to http://192.168.1.1 and login as admin/admin, go through setup wizard. Pretty simple actually.

Comment: @acejavelin I know, but is is the same for the Merlin firmware?

Comment: Yes... It's all I use.

Comment: That said... You shouldn't apply updates or flash firmware via WiFi, there is a significantly higher risk of bricking, requiring rescue flashing which requires a computer.